# Convert .wrl (VRML) to .dae (COLLADA) using MeshLab results missing colors

Tags: collada, meshlab, vrml

I used MeshLab to open a VRML .wrl model. The model was shown just fine in MeshLab. My goal was to convert .wrl to COLLADA so I can later import .dae into Unity or SketchUp, hoping I can have a working mesh with colors, see Image 1 below.

I tried to export mesh using MeshLab as COLLADA (.dae), but when I opened the .dae file in SketchUp or Unity, colors won't show up. I did see all colors in MeshLab just fine. What did I miss? Your help will be greatly appreciated.

This is how the model looks like in MeshLab:

[image]

This is how the .dae file looks like in SketchUp:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

did you try to open the dae file produced by meshlab with a text editor to check if color are present in the dae file ?

Comment: I opened it in Notepad, but not sure how to check if colors are present in the .dae? it looks like a html code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you are looking for, but I stumbled across a solution accidentally that works for me. What I wanted to do is to embed the 3D model of a PCB I designed in KiCAD in a PDF.

I needed a U3D (universal 3D) for embedding in a PDF, but after exporting it, I always ended without colors. The happy accident I stumbled upon is when I changed the "FILL COLOR" in the right panel, from "vert" to "mesh".

[image: Right panel settings that fixed the color]

This made the model in the viewport look gray,

[image: Viewport looks gray]

but after exporting it to U3D, and checking the "Vert COLOR" box in the saving options, the U3D model got the colors!

[image: Save options]

IMO this is a very weird behavior that should be changed immediately.

[image: Final image]